# Maximum and minimum $\cos(x^2+zy)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, optimization

Im trying to solve an exercise that reads: " Prove that $(0,0,0)$ is a critical point of $f(x,y,z) = \cos (x^2+yz)$ and decide if it is a minimum or a maximum value. "

The gradient of the function is $[0, 0, 0]$ and the hessian matrix is null as well. I am guessing the point is a maximum by the nature of the cosine function, but i don't really know how to prove it. (Sorry if I made grammar mistakes, not my first language) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose neighborhood around $(0,0,0)$ in a way that you have $0\leq |x^2+yz| \leq \pi /2$. You have at every point from your neighborhood that $0\leq f(x,y,z)<1$ if $(x,y,z) \neq (0,0,0)$ and $f(0,0,0)=1$.

Comment: You should also know that this neghborhood must be taken around $(0,0,0)$ so that it encircles it in a nice way so that it goes through all octants in a nice enough way, but it does indeed.